# What is the difference between "interrupt disable command register" and "interrupt clear command register"?

Tags: embedded, interrupt

In AT91SAM9263 datasheet it mentions 2 registers:

- interrupt disable command register
- interrupt clear command register

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearing an interrupt means to tell the system that you've handled the reason for the interrupt and are ready for the system to return to normal operation (like interrupting you the next time around).

Disabling an interrupt means "never interrupt me for this reason." Until and if you re-enable it.